# Series expansion of a complex function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

How do I expand a function $f(z)$ in a particular region? For example, how would I expand $f(z)=(z^2-3z+2)^{-1}$ in the region $0<|z-1|<1.$? I believe this can be done by the binomial theorem. But how to arrange things to make the binomial expansion valid?

Please give me an idea  for doing this.

Comment: Is this a Mathematica question or a Math question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Mathematica*:

```
Series[1/(z^2 - 3 z + 2), {z, 1, 10}, Assumptions -> {0 < Abs[z - 1 ]< 1}]
```

(or whatever the top-order term is that you want).

Mathematical method:

Step (i): expand the function into partial fractions -- in *Mathematica*:

```
Apart[1/(z^2 - 3 z + 2)]
```

One of the fractions you get is the the Laurent series term with negative power of $z - 1$.

Step (ii):  Expand the other term using a binomial series.

Step (iii): Add the results of Steps (i) and (ii).

Comment: okay thanks.What to do if the region is |z|<1  ?

Comment: For $|z| < 1$, you'll need to expand around $z = 0$, not $z = 1$. And from the code I provided, I think you can see how to express that in *Mathematica*.

Comment: okay thanks.Can u explain the general case?